# brew installation error : Appears homebrew is already installed

Tags: homebrew

```
unknown7cd1c37eb7ca:local shoaibali$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL   https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
-e:67: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
-e:96: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
unknown7cd1c37eb7ca:local shoaibali$ ls
CONTRIBUTING.md     foreman         hw_mp_userdata
Library         git         libexec
PortDetect.log      heroku          opt
bin         hw_mobile_userdata  share
unknown7cd1c37eb7ca:local shoaibali$
```

I have some problems with my brew when I was trying to install ffmpeg. I think I did the immature thing (note - after hours of trying) of uninstalling brew (through some article i read online) and trying to reinstall it. But the above output comes in my terminal when I try to install brew again. How can it say Homebrew is already installed when clearly the Cellar file isn't there ?

Comment: As seeing by the top comment and my comment, the issue is clearly coming from the .git folder, so I would appreciate if you mark my answer as accepted answer. The top-answer will work, too, but actually isn't "the right way"

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue. 
There was no directory called., /usr/local/Cellar but brew installation kept reporting it is already installed.

I resolved the issue by doing the following.,

Step 1 : run

```
  rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

(It reported error and didn't run successfully., but I believe it did cleanup)

Step 2 : Being from Windows world., restarted the terminal

Step 3 : Ran again

```
 ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL   https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

It ran successfully.,

Comment: gave some errors but i was able to install homebrew again

Comment: The .git folder was the problem. I removed it and homebrew installed fine.

Answer (score 7):

A simple

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/.git
```

fixed my problem and I could re-install brew

Comment: At first I was afraid that this would mess up my Xcode git configuration so I made a backup copy but in the end it didn't matter. This fixed the homebrew install problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution but running "brew cleanup" when the system doesn't detect brew is not possible XD

I came up with a possible solution... I've tried to install MacPort and also didn't installed well, but it seems to uninstall (somehow) brew, so I could reinstall it from scratch

And this time it works! So, maybe it helps somebody!

PS: I think my original problem was that I had internet connection problem when I installed Brew for the first time, and didn't installed well