# Cant install Homebrew after cancel

Tags: homebrew

I tried to install Homebrew, but my internet connection was down for a while.

When i tried to install homebrew again

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

It gives me the error:

```
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you already tried to do the steps mentioned at the error and what was the result if you tried it?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately that doesn't work because Brew isn't installed.

Comment: You should look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555378/brew-installation-error-appears-homebrew-is-already-installed

Comment: Yes, but I haven't installed Brew so I cant use the brew command.

Comment: It's the same in the thread i linked, try to follow all steps.

Comment: Yes, but I get: -bash: brew: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after running CCleaner and wait a while.